# Вывод коллекции в datagrid в C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот код WPF:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" x:Name="roomsList" Margin="0,26,0,0" />
```

Вот код C#:

```
roomsList.ItemsSource = result;
```

Вот содержимое коллекции:
[image: содержимое коллекиции]

но вместо коллекции получаю вывод такого рода:
[image: вывод]

Почему поля пустые?
Взял код из интернета и он работает как положено:

```
List<MyTable> res = new List<MyTable>(3);
res.Add(new MyTable(1, "Майкл Джексон", "Thriller", 1982));
res.Add(new MyTable(2, "AC/DC", "Back in Black", 1980));
res.Add(new MyTable(3, "Bee Gees", "Saturday Night Fever", 1977));
res.Add(new MyTable(4, "Pink Floyd", "The Dark Side of the Moon", 1973));
roomsList.ItemsSource = res;
class MyTable
    {
        public MyTable(int Id, string Vocalist, string Album, int Year)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Vocalist = Vocalist;
            this.Album = Album;
            this.Year = Year;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Vocalist { get; set; }
        public string Album { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте описание MyTable в код

Comment: @koks_rs добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `WPF` привязка работает только со свойствами, но не с полями. Следовательно, вам нужно в вашем в классе заменить поля на свойства.

Comment: result Это коллекция, а не класс

Comment: так, я чет сразу не понял вас по глупости. Сейчас попробую